# Seleccionar texto sin etiquetas Html

Tags: html, css

Si hay un texto sin etiquetas como podría seleccionarlo con css para ocultarlo?

```
<div class="content">

Hola mundo

<a href="">Enlace</a>

</div>
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo al respecto?

Comment: Ese texto está dentro una etiqueta DIV, así que no comprendo a que te refieres.
Si por "etiqueta" te refieres al identificador (id), puedes seleccionarlo a partir de la etiqueta (usando el método getElementsByTagName) o de la clase (usando el método getElementsByClassName), si conoces la posición que tiene en el documento, ya que los seleccionaría todos.

Comment: Sin etiqueta me refiero a que no esta dentro de un label o un span etc. Entonces no sabría como ocultar ese texto.

Comment: @DANIEL FERNANDO SALINAS porque querrías hacer eso?, de todas formas no creo que se pueda con CSS como tal, pues este no reconoce texto, talvez podrías con JS pero no estoy seguro, lo único que se me ocurre es hacer un color:#fff; para que se pierda con el fondo y forzar un color #000!important, para elementos con etiquetas ya que si haces un display none esto también afectara todo el contenido de tu contenedor, eso y por que el texto en si no es un elemento, por lo que tendrías que detectar un elemento mas no el texto como tal.

Comment: No es que quiera hacerlo así, el cms esta arrojando así el texto, entonces es algo que no controlo.

Comment: Si puedes seleccionar el DIV, puedes indicarle  un color transparente con un color:#00000000; por ejemplo...

Comment: La única forma de apuntar a un texto en CSS es por medio de su etiqueta que en tu caso es el `<div class="content">`.

Comment: con jquery ya logre como agregarle una etiqueta al texto y ponerle css

Comment: En tu pregunta solicitabas hacerlo con CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La mejor forma que se me ocurre para ocultarlo es ocultando el texto asignando un color invisible, cambiando la propiedad del cursor a default para que al pasar sobre el texto invisible el cursor cambiando de forma no revele la existencia del texto, y por ultimo impidiendo la selección del texto ya sea con el cursor que con `ctrl`+`a`.

Obviamente todas estas modificas tendrán que ser aplicadas al elemento que contiene dicho texto, ya sea un `div` o en última instancia el mismo `body`. Y luego habrá que reestablecer los valores de default de los demás componentes al interno del elemento interesado.

A continuación un ejemplo:

```css
.content {
    color: #0000;
    cursor: default;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.content * {
    color: #000;
    -webkit-user-select: text;
    -moz-user-select: text;
    -ms-user-select: text;
    user-select: text;
}
.content p {
    cursor: text !important;
}
.content button, .content p a {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
.content p a {
    color:blue !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    Texto Oculto
    <p>Lorem ipsum <a href="#">enlace</a> dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
    <button>Click</button>
</div>
```